# Trying to convert decimal long to binary using a char mask, but I can't succeed

Tags: c, binary, decimal

```
long number = 12501;
unsigned char mask = 1 << 7;    // create a mask 10000000
for (size_t i=0; i<(sizeof(long)*8); ++i){    // iteration for all bits of long type
    if (mask & number){
        putchar('1');
    } else {
        putchar('0');
    }
    number <<=1;    // I shift the most significant bit after every comparison
}
```

Is it possible to do a binary conversion using a char mask? My current output is: `0110100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Expected output:
`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011000011010101`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `mask`?

Comment: to compare bit to bit with &

Comment: Note that `char` can be signed... then when it is converted to `long` it will become `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF80`. define it as `unsigned char mask`

Comment: ok, edited it @AlexLop. Also, why should it be converted to long?

Comment: So, I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to print the binary presentation of the given `number`? If yes, why do you need `mask`?

Comment: Why are you iterating your loop only `sizeof(long)` times? That will only output 8 bits of a 64-bit number.

Comment: Please provide the expected output as well....

Comment: @r3mainer , you are right, I edited and fixed it. But still get the wrong output.

Comment: @Mnkisd What is the correct answer? Also why do you shift left `number` each time?

Comment: @AlexLop. yes I am trying to binary represent my dec number. I need a mask because my programming book uses it to do that, so that's it. I shift each time because I need to do a comparison bit to bit, and every time I compare I need to compare to the next bit of `number`, so I need to shift the most significant bit.

Comment: It looks like you copy paste code without understanding it. change `long number` to `unsigned long number` and change `unsigned char mask` to `unsigned long mask = 1UL << (sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT);`... And I suggest going through the relevant chapter in your book once again

Comment: @AlexLop. Three questions if I don't bother you: 1)I don't understand why I have to use an unsigned when I actually assigned `1` and shifted it. Shouldn't the mask be 10000000 even if it is signed? 2) my exercise says that I need to use long, not unsigned long, so I'm wondering how could it be possible to achieve this without changing the type of long. 3) I assume it's not possible to use a char mask to do it.. why? shouldn't `&` compare only bit to bit so shouldn't the type be useless?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215455/discussion-between-alex-lop-and-mnkisd).

Comment: Just ran this code and output was `1101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.  Are you sure you output is `0110100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica there is undefined behaviour due to shift-left of `long` type, so no wonder you got a different result

Comment: @AlexLop. Left shift of of `long` in itself is not UB.  UB occurs when shifting into the sign bit, in the 18th iteration with this code.  Although UB could mess up early input, I suspect it it more likely OP is not posting true output.  IAC, Mnkisd, is this the true output?

Comment: Mnkisd, "using a char mask"makes sense if code is reading the bytes of the `long` one by one in some sort of endian dependent order.  Otherwise use a `unsigned long` mask as well answered by [@P__J__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242413/trying-to-convert-decimal-long-to-binary-using-a-char-mask-but-i-cant-succeed#62242971)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes

Comment: Replace `if (mask & number){
        putchar('1');
    } else {
        putchar('0');
    }` with `printf("%08lX %02lX\n", (unsigned long) number, number & mask);` to get a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm sorry, actually, since I was passing the number as a function argument, I was always getting the output in the thread. But if I manually set the number to `12501` as I wrote in the thread to simplify, I get your output... I don't know why..

Comment: @Mnkisd A [mcve] is best.

Comment: Nit: the `decimal` tag isn't relevant here: you're converting a C `long` (which is already stored in binary) to a binary string representation of that `long`, so this isn't decimal-to-binary conversion in any real sense. (There _is_ a decimal-to-binary conversion present when the numeric integer literal `12501` is compiled, but all you're doing is converting an already binary long to a binary string representation of that long.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a correct version

```
void printbin(long number)
{
    unsigned long mask = 1LU << (sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT - 1);    // create a mask 10000000
    for (; mask; mask >>= 1){    // iteration for all bits of long type
            putchar((number & mask) ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Qm8Uqs

Comment: because 1 is `int` and it can be shorter than the `unsigned long`.